# Design network with redundancy

Tags: networking, internet, telephony, network-design

I need to build a redundant solution for my company. The idea is to have internet provided by two different ISP in order that if one link goes down the other link will take over.
This should be done for both Internet and telephony with ISDN.
I would like to hear what kind of solutions are available.

Thank you

Comment: It seems clear to me that you know what you want - how about doing your research instead of asking us to do it for you?

Comment: Server Fault is not a "gimmeh teh design" site any more than Stack Overflow is a "Gimmeh teh c0dez" site.  You need to come prepared with the basic research and design done, and we will be happy to help you with *specific* problems you might be having. If you want a network designed for you from the ground up you should consider hiring someone from http://careers.stackoverflow.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want is a dual Wan device with either a load-balancing or fail-over configuration. Lots of vendors provide this depending on your company size.

You will have your 2 ISP routers connecting to this device, if one connection goes down the other wan port will activate.